# 128MB virtual address space is enough to access huge High memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am understanding Linux memory management. Following diagram shows mapping between virtual address space and physical address space.

[image: Virtual address space to physical address space mapping]

my doubht here is 128MB of virtual address spcae is sufficent to access high memory?

Comment: A reasonable question, but you might start by thinking about why the kernel might need additional memory, and if such a situation would't be better handled in the 64-bit realm.

Comment: I think the additional memory will be used by both kernel space and user space(kernel will allocate memory for user space request also through page fault . is it correct?).                                                        My understanding is, the virtual address space will be split as 3G(user space)/1G(kernel space). The 1G kernel space will be divide as 896MB + 128MB.   How the user space address will be mapped to physical address, will the user space virtual address map to kernel space 128MB address and then it is map to physical address using kmap?

Comment: Virtual address space is not limited by size of physical memory.

Comment: Hello, user3693586. I am also trying to understand the concepts of kernel virtual addresses and high memory. What book or other source is your figure taken from? I would like to see if the source can help me understand better. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Tim, I think I have created this diagram using power point based on initial understanding. I used to refer Linux Kernel Development and Linux Device Driver books. I have gone through https://www.quora.com/Linux-Kernel/What-is-the-difference-between-high-memory-and-normal-memory , 
http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_9815359e01012yup.html links.

Answer (score 0):

> Is 128MB of virtual address space sufficient to access high memory?

Yes.

In the beginning, 32-bit processors had no way to even "think" about addresses bigger than 4GB. It was literally impossible to add more than 4GB of RAM.

Worse, Linux needs to stay mapped in virtual memory at all times. So 32-bit apps can only use the bottom 3GB of virtual memory.

Later, Intel added a special way for the processor to address more RAM. It has extra bits in it's virtual memory mapper, so you have 4GB of virtual addresses, but 64GB of physical addresses.

So even without high memory, multiple processes can be using "all" your RAM, even though each process sees 3GB of RAM.

So what is High Memory?  It's a place to make transient mappings to data. It stores things like cached disk blocks that "might" be needed later, but aren't used by any particular processes at the moment. When someone needs them, the kernel can get to them.